# How do I recreate this plot with python libraries?

Tags: plot, networkx

I want to create the plot of a co-occurence network from here: https://www.kaggle.com/code/mmmarchetti/game-of-thrones-network-analysis
I think they used LaTex. I want to create something similar with python libraries. Which libraries do I use, and how do I go about this?

They used degree/pagerank centrality as label sizes. Colors as clusters (I do not necesseraly need this). Weight as edge thickness. They also only plotted the top 50-something nodes from a book (there are 187 nodes in the first book).

I tried around with networkx but didn't remotely get a clear result. Labels and nodes are jumbled on top of each other.

Comment: Here's my answer to a similar question that might serve your purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76290724/nice-plot-of-network-divided-into-communities/76326843#76326843