# Nice plot of network divided into communities

Tags: python, plot, networkx, modularity

I have a graph of cities divided into communities with modularity for different years. Each community assignment of nodes lies in a separate dataset according to the year (e.g.community2000 for year 2000 and so on).
The graph G contains nodes as follows:

```
{'Node': {0: 'albany', 1: 'almaty', 2: 'amsterdam'}}
```

and each ode has a number of edges (below some for albany):

```
{'Source': {0: 'albany',
  1: 'albany',
  2: 'albany',
  3: 'albany',
  4: 'albany',
  5: 'albany',
  6: 'albany',
  7: 'albany',
  8: 'albany',
  9: 'albany'},
 'Target': {0: 'almaty',
  1: 'amsterdam',
  2: 'ankara',
  3: 'athens',
  4: 'atlanta',
  5: 'auckland',
  6: 'austin',
  7: 'bangalore',
  8: 'bangkok',
  9: 'barcelona'}}
```

To each node is attribute a community in G.nodes[node]['Community'] which has been done via the available community dataframe (community_df) that I had as follows:

```
    for node in G.nodes():
        city = node
        community = community_df.loc[community_df['city'] == city, 'cluster'+community_filename[-4:]].values[0]
        G.nodes[node]['Community'] = community
```

The code that I am currently using for making the plot of the network is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a dictionary to map community labels to unique integers
community_labels = {}
next_community_label = 0

# Assign a unique integer label to each community
for node in G.nodes():
    community = G.nodes[node]['Community']
    if community not in community_labels:
        community_labels[community] = next_community_label
        next_community_label += 1

# Create a dictionary to map cluster labels to unique integers within each community
cluster_labels = {}

# Remove self-loops
G.remove_edges_from(nx.selfloop_edges(G))

# Draw the network graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.3)  # Layout algorithm for node positioning
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

for community in community_labels.values():
    nodes = [node for node, attr in G.nodes(data=True) if attr['Community'] == community]
    
    # Assign cluster labels within each community
    for node in nodes:
        cluster = community_df.loc[community_df['city'] == node, 'cluster' + community_filename[-4:]].values[0]
        cluster_labels[node] = cluster
    
    node_colors = [cluster_labels[node] for node in nodes]
    
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=nodes, node_size=200, node_color=node_colors, cmap='viridis')
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=G.edges, alpha=0.1, width=0.5)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=8, font_color='black', labels={node: node for node in nodes})

plt.axis('off')
plt.title("Network of Cities Divided into Communities and Clusters")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The result of such a code is unreadable and not divided into communities as I wished:

[image]

My desired outcome would be something like this (with city names as labels of nodes):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of [gravis](https://robert-haas.github.io/gravis-docs), a graph visualization package for Python which can be used to plot graph objects from libraries like NetworkX, graph-tool, igraph and more.

Here's an example of creating a graph with NetworkX, detecting communities in it, assigning colors to each node according to community membership and then visualizing it. The same should be possible with your data.

```
import gravis as gv
import networkx as nx

g = nx.les_miserables_graph()

centrality = nx.algorithms.degree_centrality(g)
nx.set_node_attributes(g, centrality, 'size')

communities = nx.algorithms.community.greedy_modularity_communities(g)
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'pink']
for community, color in zip(communities, colors):
    for node in community:
        g.nodes[node]['color'] = color

gv.d3(g, use_node_size_normalization=True, node_size_normalization_max=30,
      use_edge_size_normalization=True, edge_size_data_source='weight', edge_curvature=0.3)
```

The output is an interactive visualization in a browser window or notebook cell, which can also be exported as static image in png or other formats:
[image: gravis_demo]

Answer (score 2):

Here is something to get you started:

The basic idea is to use `nx.spring_layout` to generate positions, but to do so individually for each community.

```
#dummy graph
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(np.random.rand(100,100)>0.9)
for node in G.nodes:
    G.nodes[node]['community'] = np.random.randint(0,4)

# organise communities:
communities = {}
for node, data in G.nodes(data=True):
    c = data['community']
    if c not in communities:
        communities[c] = [node]
    else:
        communities[c].append(node)
        
# build individual positions for each community:
# add offsets to move clusters around:
offsets = [[0,0], [0,5], [5,0], [5,5]]
pos = {}
for offset, nodes in zip(offsets, communities.values()):
    community_position = nx.spring_layout(G.subgraph(nodes), center=offset)
    pos = {**pos, **community_position}
    
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos)
```